# Comparing a current timestamp date in JSP with dates from a database

Tags: database, jsp

Hi I have got a JSP page which displays the current date and time to the user after they have logged in, my jsp code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /25893-javascript-current-date-and-time-.html
        var todayDate=new Date();
        var date=todayDate.getDate();
        var month=todayDate.getMonth()+1;
        var year=todayDate.getFullYear();
        var hours=todayDate.getHours();
        var minutes=todayDate.getMinutes();
        var seconds=todayDate.getSeconds();
        document.writeln("You have logged in at: "+ hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds);
        document.writeln("on: " + date + "/" + month + "/" + year);
    </script>
```

I want to compare the current date and time that the user has logged in with the date and time from a database (In the database I already have a field called startDateTime with the DATETIME datatype) and display the row from the database to the user (I already have a couple of date fields in the database). Does anyone know what's the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Just create date in JSP instead of in JS.

```html
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
```

Assuming that the DB field in question is also as `java.util.Date` available by `${bean.startDateTime}`, you could just compare it as follows:

```html
<c:if test="${bean.startDateTime lt now}">
    Start date time is in the past.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${bean.startDateTime gt now}">
    Start date time is in the future.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${bean.startDateTime eq now}">
    Start date time is identical to now.
</c:if>
```

Comment: The startDate field in my database has the DATETIME datatype which also has the time attached to the date. I need to compare the current date and time when the user logs in to all the date and time fields in the database and display the row(s) that match to the user.

Comment: You're not terribly clear in the concrete functional requirement. You're basically saying "I want to compare 2 dates". You're not clear as to *how* and *why* you would like to compare them. Do you want an exact match with current datetime? Use `eq` or `==` then, as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: I want to compare the current date and time when the user logs in e.g. (You have logged in at: 17 : 58 : 58 on: 20/2/2013) with the datetime field from the database and if both the current date and times match with those in the database then i want to display the row(s) back to the user. I hope that is clear enough

Comment: Then use `<c:if test="${bean.startDateTime eq now}">`. Or, if it needs to be compared at SQL level, just set it in `WHERE` clause.